# Database design - Having columns in the main table vs having a separate table

Tags: database

Let's imagine you have a house . That house can have a swimming pool, a garden or anything else.

As we want to list those "features", I will create a feature table.

Now I will have a table called `House` and a table called `Feature`.

Should I include the features in the `Feature` table as columns in the `House` table, or it would be better to have a `House_feature` table where `House.id` and `Feature.id` are the primary keys?

In past projects I would use the second option, but I keep thinking that when you want to query, it is generally easier to have everything as columns. What would be the cons other than I would need to manually add columns in the future if I want to include any new feature?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic many-to-many relation - a house can have multiple features and a feature can be in multiple houses.

So you need a mapping table `House_feature`.

Any other option would not be normalized and only leads to problems.

Comment: Thanks - which kind of problems?

Comment: Just google *database normalisation*. There are so many articles about it

Comment: I did, but I don't see why the database would not be normalized by having the house features as boolean columns in the House table?

Comment: If the content of your data has impact on your table structure then this is bad. Adding new house features leads to adding new columns. But a database schema should not change if possible.